# Can I file taxes in the state where I own a home even if I don't live there?

Tags: united-states, taxes, travel

I've owned a home in New Jersey for 20 years.  I work remotely, from wherever I am.  Last year, my family and I traveled around the country for 7 months, and I worked throughout this time. Then we settled in New York, but still own the house in New Jersey.  The companies that I worked for are not in either state.

So where do I file taxes?  I didn't live anywhere for more than a couple of days for 7 months, and then I lived in a rental house in New York for 4 months.  But since I own a house in New Jersey, can I file as if I lived there the whole year?  Or do I have to file in New York for the months I was living there?  And how do I handle the months when I was traveling?  If I say I lived in New Jersey for those months, can I just say I lived there the whole year?

Comment: Working in multiple states gets complicated.  Every state has different rules.  Take a look at [this TurboTax post](https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/1900021-when-do-you-need-to-file-tax-returns-in-multiple-states) for an overview.

Comment: Were you a W-2 employee?

Comment: Just to make it a bit more complicated, I had W2 earnings from one company, and 1099 from a few others.  None of the companies are based in NY or NJ though.

Comment: What state did the employer withhold for on the W-2, if any?  That wouldn't be binding, but if you don't claim much income for that state then you need to file to get the money back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You file in every State you worked in. Technically, while you're in a State and you work - your earnings are sourced to that State.

Also, since you were domiciled in New Jersey - you file there as well, as your residency State. From the time you moved to NY - you should check whether you're still considered a resident in NJ, but you're likely to be considered a resident in NY, so you file a part-year return there for that period. It is possible to be considered resident in more than one State at the same time, so it may get even more complicated.